# JuMP - Gurobi Callbacks Example from documentation returns an error

Tags: callback, julia, gurobi, heuristics, julia-jump

I copy paste the example from [Gurobi's documentation](https://github.com/jump-dev/Gurobi.jl#callbacks) about callbacks.

```
using JuMP, Gurobi, Test

model = direct_model(Gurobi.Optimizer())
@variable(model, 0 <= x <= 2.5, Int)
@variable(model, 0 <= y <= 2.5, Int)
@objective(model, Max, y)
cb_calls = Cint[]
function my_callback_function(cb_data, cb_where::Cint)
    # You can reference variables outside the function as normal
    push!(cb_calls, cb_where)
    # You can select where the callback is run
    if cb_where != GRB_CB_MIPSOL && cb_where != GRB_CB_MIPNODE
        return
    end
    # You can query a callback attribute using GRBcbget
    if cb_where == GRB_CB_MIPNODE
        resultP = Ref{Cint}()
        GRBcbget(cb_data, cb_where, GRB_CB_MIPNODE_STATUS, resultP)
        if resultP[] != GRB_OPTIMAL
            return  # Solution is something other than optimal.
        end
    end
    # Before querying `callback_value`, you must call:
    Gurobi.load_callback_variable_primal(cb_data, cb_where)
    x_val = callback_value(cb_data, x)
    y_val = callback_value(cb_data, y)
    # You can submit solver-independent MathOptInterface attributes such as
    # lazy constraints, user-cuts, and heuristic solutions.
    if y_val - x_val > 1 + 1e-6
        con = @build_constraint(y - x <= 1)
        MOI.submit(model, MOI.LazyConstraint(cb_data), con)
    elseif y_val + x_val > 3 + 1e-6
        con = @build_constraint(y + x <= 3)
        MOI.submit(model, MOI.LazyConstraint(cb_data), con)
    end
    if rand() < 0.1
        # You can terminate the callback as follows:
        GRBterminate(backend(model))
    end
    return
end
# You _must_ set this parameter if using lazy constraints.
MOI.set(model, MOI.RawOptimizerAttribute("LazyConstraints"), 1)
MOI.set(model, Gurobi.CallbackFunction(), my_callback_function)
optimize!(model)
@test termination_status(model) == MOI.OPTIMAL
@test primal_status(model) == MOI.FEASIBLE_POINT
@test value(x) == 1
@test value(y) == 2
```

Which results in the following error:

```
julia> include("test.jl")
Academic license - for non-commercial use only
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: RawOptimizerAttribute not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./Base.jl:26
 [2] top-level scope at /home/julien/Desktop/test.jl:43
 [3] include(::String) at ./client.jl:457
 [4] top-level scope at REPL[20]:1
in expression starting at /home/julien/Desktop/test.jl:43
```

And this is very strange to me as I did not change anything from the code given in the doc.
My package verions are:

```
Julia Version 1.5.2
[2e9cd046] Gurobi v0.9.4
[4076af6c] JuMP v0.21.5
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Please try with the latest versions of Gurobi (v0.11.1), JuMP (v1.0.0), and Julia (1.6 or 1.7). JuMP 0.21.5 is nearly two years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an old version of JuMP installed. Please update to 1.0 (with compatibility guarantees going forward to prevent these issues in future!).